# Sqlite with Substr to catch parts of strings

Tags: sql, sqlite

Lets suppose that we have this value inside a row **23/06/2014 01:57:44 PM** and we need to catch only the number **06**, for this I try the code below:

```
substr(aRow, 3, -18)
```

Is correct?

Answer (score 1):

In SQLITE `substr` syntax is

```
substr( string, start_position, [ length ] ).
```

> The substr(X,Y,Z) function returns a substring of input string X that begins with the Y-th character and which is Z characters long

So here try

```
substr(aRow, 4, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`substr(aRow, 4, 2)` might be more appropriate for this situation.

`substr(aRow, 3, -18)` will result in 23.

Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fb6e9/4

```
create table test(aRow text);
insert into test values ('23/06/2014 01:57:44 PM');

select substr(aRow, 4, 2) as val from test
union all
select substr(aRow, 3, -18) as val from test

Result:
06
23
```

Answer (score 0):

The Y parameter in substr(X,Y,Z) starts with 1 not 0, so it should be 4.
Also the Z parameter in substr(X,Y,Z) should be the number of characters. In this case it should be 2.